# One render picture and two questions (I think both are related to the glass material)

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm making a room and I have two questions after I saw the render.

1. The sliding door panel behind the window is very dark.
2. The lower left edges of the table have some light under the glass top that looks strange. I'm guessing it might be from the bevel of the edge and the glass material?

Any idea how to solve both? Many thanks.

ps. The chair is the bonus material from Blender Guru's architecture academy. I didn't make that.

[image: Test render]

[image: Render setting]

[image: Glass material]

-------Update--------

So I saw that my IOR setting for glass is also wrong, I've adjusted it in the following render.

I decided to try two different camera angles just to see if it makes any difference.

The 1st and 3rd image are the original 2D window pointed out by @gandalf3 . The 2nd and 4th image are the adjusted 3D window created with a cube.

I saw the difference, of course, caused by the IOR. The 3D windows seem to affect slightly how the panel looked behind the glass. Is there any other way I should test to see if this is even abnormal? Many thanks.

[image: Camera angle 1, original 2D window with adjusted IOR 1.44]

[image: Camera angle 1, 3D cube window with adjusted IOR 1.44]

[image: Camera angle 2, original 2D window with adjusted IOR 1.44]

[image: Camera angle 2, 3D cube window with adjusted IOR 1.44]

Comment: Could you [post a .blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), it is hard to figure out what is wrong

Comment: The Light Path node is your issue, mute the final Mix Shader by selecting it and pressing `M`

Comment: I didn't know you can mute the node! Thanks. Although it didn't seem to change the result or I just didn't know how to properly mute it. A red line crossed out the node? Anyway, the file is here https://www.dropbox.com/s/pkd0otiyicgnlor/FrenchDoorHouse15-03-10.blend?dl=0

Comment: Thanks for the file. Muting the node was just a hunch, we'll have to look deeper to figure out what is going on

Comment: The lights under the table seem perfectly reasonable to me, they are caused by [total internal reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_Internal_Reflection) of light coming through the window and sliding door. As for the darkening, I'm not completely sure I'm looking at the right thing.. However I have noticed that your windows are two dimensional (no thickness) and are connected to the door frames. This might cause some issues, in addition to the extra mix shader.

Comment: Thanks @gandalf3. I've made the adjustment to the windows. Please see the renders in the post (I don't know how to post pictures in the comments). Changing the windows into 3D definitely explained why I was looking at strange distortion when the IOR is 1.44. But now I'm not sure whether the darkened panel is abnormal or not. Any suggestion what else I can try to test?